# Is it possible to load a new angular module at runtime?

Tags: javascript, angular, frontend, runtime

Okay I am pretty new to **Angular**. But I think I do understand how **lazy-loading** works here.

As far as **lazy-loading** goes, the **routes** that we mention, when **visited**, will load the **bundled js** file of the **module** from the server. So this bundled js file must be placed here at **build time**.

Now I have a question that is it possible to **inject an angular module at runtime** such that **it was not a part of the build phase**. It's a new module that was **created** **independent of the main codebase** and I want to inject it. Please **don't suggest micro frontends** for this since that is out of scope as per my requirement.

Also the same module **should be accessible at a **new** route**. I am not aware if the code for this route also has to be included at runtime or if at build time it can be done and not impact the build process.

I am working with **Angular 9.1**

Comment: Sure, read more [here](https://indepth.dev/lazy-loading-angular-modules-with-ivy/). Just possible with ivy though (angular >=9 )

Comment: @PoulKruijt But this needs the module to be present at build time right? Otherwise how will Ivy compile it? I don't want module to be in my codebase at all. It's entirely a separate angular module that I want to inject at runtime at a new route.

Comment: I think you should go back and think about why you want something like this. What problem are you facing that you have such an obscure requirement. Especially if you rule out micro frontend, which seem to be exactly what you are asking at the moment

Comment: @PoulKruijt Let's just say I need to convince someone that this is not possible. I know micro frontend solves this. Because I have done that in React. That's why I am literally looking for an answer that says :- Nope not possible and gives an explanation as to why.  Since I am new to Angular, I don't want to rule out the possibility but from my past experience , I know, this is like an obscure requirement.

Comment: Maybe you can take a look at angular custom elements, and just use a dynamic script tag in your code to load this. That might work